# Infinite Dimensional Topological Vector Space

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). To make $V$ a topological space, we may choose the sets $f^{-1}(U)$ as a sub-basis, where $f$ ranges over all linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) and $U$ ranges over all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$).

If $V$ is infinite dimensional, one may define two (different?) topologies on $V$, one is repeating the same definition as in the finite case, another is to give $V$ the weak topology determined by all finite-dimensional subspaces; that is, a subset $C\subset V$ is closed if and only if $C\cap W$ is closed for every finite dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$.

My question is, are these two definitions the same? If not, which one is finer, and which one is more natural and frequently used?

Comment: Did you try to prove them equal?  Or one contained in the other?  You should provide your attempts, before expecting us to do it for you.

Comment: For practical purposes, the first definition is hardly ever used. Under the topology you wrote down the topological dual and the algebraic dual are the same, and so it rules out any infinite dimensional normed vector spaces as an application.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong for your comment! May I clarify what you mean by "the topological dual and the algebraic dual are the same"? Why it rules out infinite dimensional normed vector spaces as an application?

Comment: Your definition implies every linear map is continuous. And then please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space